# Wordpress format HTML issue

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm running through a query in a shortcode. The query generated HTML syntax is ok except for the first two iterations. I've got no idea why this happens.

This the HTML I get:

[image: screenshot]

It should be a list of  wrapped titles. but the first one is wrapped in

tag and  tags for some reason.

Here's my loop:

```
global $post;

  $case_studies_args = array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies');
  $case_studies_loop = new WP_Query( $case_studies_args );
    while ( $case_studies_loop->have_posts() ) : $case_studies_loop->the_post();
      $cs_shortcode_bg_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->ID,'case_study_tile_background_image','full' ), 'full');

      $html .= '<a class="case_study_tile shortcode-case_study_tile" style="background-image:url('. $cs_shortcode_bg_image[0] .')" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">';
      $html .= '<h2>' . get_the_title($post->ID ) .'</h2>';
      $html .= '<span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'case_study_strapline' , true).'</span>';
      $html .= '</a>';

    endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
  return $html;
```

Any ideas why WP behaves like this?

Comment: It's probably `wpautop()` conflicting with your html. I'd try disabling it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: Actually, I take that back. Where the heck does `$html` come from? That's likely the culprit.

Comment: It's not wpautop(), it's one of first things I disable when starting new theme. $html is just a variable, basically a string I return. I found a way to solve this - but I still don't get the cause. When <h2> is removed from $html string, the formatting is fixed. It'd be great to know why is this happening though. It seems like a bug to me. I use plenty different loops on the same page, some in template, others in shortcodes and plugins. I have no other explanation to this.